# what are all the page level events that get fired when a button is clicked?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

This was a interview question

what are the page level events that get fired when a button is clicked in Asp.net

will all the page level events get fired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No! not all the events get fired on click of the button(PostBack). `Page_Init` event will not be fired on postbacks. You can study more on the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

**1 - Page.Init + Control.Init for every control on the Web Form**
The first stage in the page life cycle is initialization. After the page's control tree is populated with all the statically declared controls in the .aspx source the Init event is fired. First, the Init event for the Page object occurs, then Init event occurs for each control on the Page. Viewstate information is not available at this stage.

**2 - Page.LoadViewState**
After initialization, ASP.NET loads the view state for the page. ViewState contains the state of the controls the last time the page was processed on the server.

**3 - Page.ProcessPostData**
Post Data gets read from the request and control values are applied to control initalized in stage 1.

**4 - Page.Load + Control.Load for each control on the Page**
If this is the first time the page is being processed (Page.IsPostback property), initial data binding is performed here.

**5 - "Change" events are fired for controls (TextChanged, SelectedIndexChanged, and similar)**
The current value (from Post Data) is compared to the original value located in the ViewState. If there is a difference "Changed" events are raised.

6 - Server-side events are fired for any validation controls

**7 - Button.Click + Button.Command**
The Click and Command events are fired for the button that caused the postback

**8 - Page.PreRender + Control.PreRender**

**9 - Page.SaveViewState**
New values for all the controls are saved to the view state for another round-trip to the server.

**10 - Page.Render**

Reference : http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa051705a.htm